# EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly in spring boot ( while creating New Spring Starter Project)

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, ssl-certificate, spring-tool-suite

I don't have eclipse installed in my machine. But java installed of version 11 and set the path variables.[image]. Added image. Kindly help to resolve this

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Is this a dialog from the Spring Tools plugin? If yes, which version of the Spring Tools plugin?

Comment: Looks like either a temporary network glitch or a proxy server in between that causes trouble.